# PHP namespaces, requires and relative paths issue

Tags: php

I am using both namespace and require and i'm a bit confused: require means I basically load that file into memory, and namespaces basically gives me an auxiliary way to navigate and 'categorize' my classes, yet I have no idea if I'm doing it right as it looks messy.

I did resolve to tutorials yet they explain the basic gist of it and never go into design and best practice.

**my structure:**

```
root

root>models>User.php

root>services>API.php

root>services>Database.php

root>services>Logger.php
```

#### User.php

```
namespace Models;
use Services\API;
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../services/API.php' ;

class User{}
```

#### API.php

```
namespace Services;
class API{}
```

Dealing with Laravel for more than a while I've never seen any class that has a require/include in them, i'm sure they are using some hoisting mechanism to call those files, yet everything there looks nice and tucked in.

Please suggest / teach me how to use namespaces where ATM my immediate task is to call API from my models directory classes / Model namespace.

Comment: One word ... autoloading. Look it up.

Comment: the minimum number of letters in a comment is 15 chars, good thing you gave a prologue and stipulated the word count so no one would be confused.